# XSD: multiple types with same element name

Tags: xml, types, xsd

I am using xsd for xml validation. I need to describe one element with two types.

```
   <xsd:choice>
                            <xsd:element name="num" minOccurs="1" type="xsd:integer" fixed="0"/>
                            <xsd:element name="num" minOccurs="1" type="xsd:positiveInteger"/>
</xsd:choice>
```

When I validate xml with num = 0 validation is successful, but when I validate xml with num value = 1 or greater validation fails with error. How to describe this case correct?

Comment: If I change element position in xsd velidation with num = 1 is successful, with num = 0 unsuccessful.

Comment: Why u want to two elements with same name?You can use two different names.

Comment: I want only one element. In one case num value must be = 0 , in other case num = 1,2,3 etc. I know about nonNegativeInteger type, but in the end this types will be complex types.

Answer (score 6):

I would use xs:nonNegativeInteger for this use case:

```
<xs:element name="num" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger">
```

If you want an element to support multiple types you can use a union:

```
<xs:element name="num" default="0">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:union memberTypes="xs:integer xs:positiveInteger" />
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! But what about if in case with num = 1,2,3 etc(xs:positiveInteger) I need uniq constraint. How to add this constraint to mentioned xsd declaration?

Comment: @Georgy Gobozov - By unique constraint, you mean you want to the value of the num element to occur only once per document?

Comment: No, num this is internal element of other complex element - applicant. If applicant occures more than one time I want that num will be unique.

Comment: found a solution. Add unique constraint to root element of my xsd

Answer (score 3):

You can't have two element particles in the same complex type with the same name and different types (this rule is called "Element Declarations Consistent" if you want to look it up). Part of the reason is that XSD is used not only for validation, but also for data typing, e.g. in Java data binding.

But I think what you are looking for here is a union type.